# Getting the integer from this php function that shows how many elements are being viewed?

Tags: php

I got this function:

```
<?php bbp_get_topic_pagination_count(); ?>
```

and the final output is something like this:

> Viewing 10 replies - 1 through 10 (of 13 total)

I would like to just get (filter) the "total" (13 in the example above).

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
function custom_function() {
    global $bbp;
    return bbp_number_format( $bbp->reply_query->found_posts );
}
```

Comment: But Wesley did answer right before me. It could be possible that I have stolen his answer.

Comment: @Jens Struwe OK then I give it to Wesley (I guess that's fair, he answered first).

Comment: Yes, but I would have answered even before Wesley if there were not this dreaded and unreadable captcha.

Answer (score 1):

```
function custom_bbp_get_total() {
    global $bbp;
    $total = bbp_number_format( $bbp->reply_query->found_posts );
    return $total;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this number is fetched from `$bbp->reply_query->found_posts`.  Just use that expression.  (Make sure to issue `global $bbp;` if you are going to fetch the value from inside a function.)

Answer (score 0):

Well just a wild guess but given that `$bbp` is a global, and assuming that it isn't altered in any detrimental way as a side effect of executing that function, you should be able to copy exactly what is assigned to `$total` in the function, i.e. you can get the value like this:

```
$total = $bbp->reply_query->found_posts;
```